# How to unfreeze the terminal in VScode after CTRL+S?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I purposefully froze my terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in visual studio code, so that I could inspect the fast log messages scrolling through. Normally, you can unfreeze it again with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>.

However, it seems that vscode catches this second shortcut and instead of unfreezing my terminal, it opens this popup in the middle of the screen - which disappears as soon as I release the keys...
[image: List of various actions]
This seems to be called the "Quick Open View".

I assume that there is a way to send the "unfreeze" signal to the terminal. How?

---

My solution for now was to detach tmux in vscode, then connect over ssh using a normal terminal, attach tmux, send the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> there, detach and exit again, and re-attach in vscode.

Comment: haha shame you needed to do that :) but gj

Comment: You've saved me a tonne of frustration here. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

you can remove any shortcuts you want. go to file > preference > keyboard shortcuts
type "ctrl q"
and adapt as you wish

Comment: Hm sure, thanks, but does that mean there is no intended way to do this with the defaults?

Comment: i also found this useful in settings.json
    "terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": true,

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this issue,
I found that if you go into File -> Preferences -> keyboard shortcuts

When you find the Ctrl-q shortcut, you can right click it and choose to remove it,

then the Ctrl-q will work to resume the terminal